# Cannot resolve symbol 'FilenameUtils

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, java-17, apache-commons-io

I need your help, I have problem with my code I want to save image file and I can't use "FileUtils" however I import "org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils" and add the dependency
( I work with maven IntelliJ)
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBR56.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLIZl.png)

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version> <!-- or the latest version available -->
        </dependency>

Comment: Please do never post screenshots of text/code. Images are not searchable. Just copy and paste the text into your question and format it as code. Is your comment an answer jr should it extend you question? If it is the latter please edit your question instead and add it there.

Comment: The class you use is `FilenameUtils` not `FileUtils`, thus you need an additional import. IntelliJ should show you potential ways to fix that problem.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode